# Export Users and their Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: users, advanced-custom-fields, export

I've google it but i am still looking for a solution.

Is there a plugin or method to export wordpress users with their advanced custom fields?

I don't want to export ACFs structure but users' data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Export Users to CSV](https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-users-to-csv/) plugin does support exporting user fields, out of the box. That should work.

And, later if you intend to import them to another site, you can try [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/) plugin, but be aware that this plugin isn't free.

Comment: "This plugin has been closed as of January 28, 2019 and is not available for download. Reason: Security Issue." :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [Export Users With Meta](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-export-with-their-meta-data/) plugin.

It's free, it exports to CSV, and it allows you to select the fields you want to export:
[image]

***PS:*** I am the author of this plugin, but I created it after I have found this page but found no answer (the answer suggests a plugin that was closed due to security issues).

Answer (score 0):

You can try a plugin like [export user data](http://wordpress.org/plugins/export-user-data/stats/). It can export users with the user meta. ACF should be from what I remember storing user custom fields as user meta data so they should be compatible, but this will depend on the export plugin.

If this plugin doesn't work you'll need to write a simple script that would loop through the required users with WP_User_Query then get the user data based on user id from ACF which is explained [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/). You'd then have to print or compile a file in what ever format you want with the data.

Sorry I can't be more specific without knowing the type of file you're trying to export and if and how it needs to be imported elsewhere.

Comment: Export User Data doesn't work, i need to build and export script

Comment: What do you need the export for? Is it for reporting, backing up or for importing elsewhere?

Comment: I need to import and export users's custom fields. Export is for reporting in xls.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Mike? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunely